# Error while trying to put items into a spinner - Android

Tags: android, sqlite, error-handling, spinner, android-spinner

I am currently trying to add items from a SQLite Database and put them into a spinner.  The following shows code for database and main activity, if there is anything else that needs added, please say so.  I also showed the error occurring.

Error:

```
02-24 14:01:59.222  23660-23660/com.example.bank_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.bank_app.main_menu_activity.onOptionsItemSelected(main_menu_activity.java:149)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2640)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1171)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:630)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:200)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4489)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18803)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Main Activity Code:

```
List<String> SpinnerArray = db.getAccountsNames();

// Outputs items in SpinnerArray to logcat
/*for (int j = 0; j < SpinnerArray.size(); j++)
{
    Log.d("Output", j + ": " + SpinnerArray.get(j).toString());
}*/

ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpinnerArray);  
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
Spinner accountSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
accountSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

Database Handler:

```
// Getting All Account Names return ArrayList<Account)
public ArrayList<String> getAccountsNames()
{
    ArrayList<String> accountNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String selectQry = "SELECT * FROM " + Table_Account;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQry, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            //Account account = new Account();
            //account.setAccountName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));

            // Add to account list
            accountNameList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return accountNameList;
}
```

**I know the SpinnerArray has information in it, because the items get printed to logcat, however my error occurs somewhere in following code:**

```
ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpinnerArray);  
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
Spinner accountSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
accountSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

**Thanks for your help!**

XML - (This is xml for a custom alert dialog)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_root"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Select account to delete: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your error is in line `main_menu_activity.java:149`

Comment: Can you share the code you have in `onOptionsItemSelected()` call back in your activity? The code is crashing at line 149. Check its not related to your spinner but to the options menu.

Comment: Line 149 is accountSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spinner with id `spinner1` as you say is in a custom alert dialog. But `findViewById()` in an activity tries to find it from the activity view hierarchy. Your dialogs are not part of the activity hierarchy. You must search the dialog hierarchy for that.

For example, change

```
Spinner accountSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

to

```
Spinner accountSpinner = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

where `dialog` is your dialog that is showing.

(You don't really show how you're inflating the dialog so there's possibly a better way for that.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpinnerArray);                    
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

Spinner accountSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
accountSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Still does not work, I get a error occurring at accountSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter); part of the code.

Comment: Are you sure the spinner has the id 'spinner1' ? I ask because I've made this mistake which resulted in a NullPointer

Comment: Yes, when I changed my code to what you had, the error above is the same error I received.

Comment: 02-24 14:38:39.610  24953-24953/com.example.bank_app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.bank_app.main_menu_activity.onOptionsItemSelected(main_menu_activity.java:155)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2640)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1171)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to problem is as shown thanks to help of laalto!

```
        case R.id.action_delete_account:
        {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.delete_account);
            dialog.setTitle("Delete Account");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);

            spn = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            List<String> SpinnerArray = db.getAccountsNames();
            /*for (int j = 0; j < SpinnerArray.size(); j++)
            {
                Log.d("Output", j + ": " + SpinnerArray.get(j).toString());
            }*/

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpinnerArray);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            //Log.d("Output", Integer.toString(dataAdapter.getCount()));
            spn.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            //TextView title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            btnDelete = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            btnCancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);

            btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    displayListView();
                }
            });
            btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
        default:
        {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```